# How to get expand_grid to the pipe?

Tags: r

This is probably very stupid question but I got stuck with it.

I have perfectly working code here in R:

```
var <- my_tibble %>%
       split(.$country) %>%
       imap(~ function_xyz(.x$index, .y))

var2 <- var %>%
        expand_grid(var[["list_a"]], var[["list_b"]]) %>%
        select(column_a, column_b)
```

But I would like all that only in one pipe but I don't get how I should do it. Expand_grid refers to variable var in current solution but I don't understand where I should refer in one pipe solution. As variable var doesn't exist then yet if I just add all together.

Comment: Working for you but not for us because `my_tibble` is not shared.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `var` with `.` inside the `expand_grid` statement?

Comment: @AndrewGustar That works perfectly. I knew this was some very stupid mistake here... Thanks a lot!